# Issue with Bootstrap scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, scroll

I downloaded a responsive Wordpress theme for a single page site. The theme uses Bootstrap scrolled navigation.

I am familiar with JQuery/JS but by no means competent.

I have hit an issue as follows:-

My main menu comprises a number of menu options. When the visitor clicks on a menu option bootstrap scrolls to the top of the section with the corresponding CSS ID. The scroll applies a top margin to the  element to avoid the top of the section being scrolled to being partially hidden under the navbar.

The navbar clicks are handled by the followinhg code:-

```
  $('a.header').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#header').offset().top - '60'}, 1000,
      function() {
        scrollingfn();
      });
    return false;
  });

  $('a.service').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#service').offset().top - '60'}, 1000,
      function() {
        scrollingfn();
      });
    return false;
  });

  $('a.portfolio').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#portfolio').offset().top - '60'}, 1000,
      function() {
        scrollingfn();
      });
    return false;
  });

  $('a.testimonial').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#testimonial').offset().top - '60'}, 1000,
      function() {
        scrollingfn();
      });
    return false;
  });

  $('a.pricing').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#pricing').offset().top - '60'}, 1000,
      function() {
        scrollingfn();
      });
    return false;
  });

  $('a.aboutus').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#aboutus').offset().top - '60'}, 1000,
      function() {
        scrollingfn();
      });
    return false;
  });

$('a.team').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#team').offset().top - '60'}, 1000,
      function() {
        scrollingfn();
      });
    return false;
  });

$('a.contactus').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$('#contactus').offset().top - '60'}, 1000,
      function() {
        scrollingfn();
      });
    return false;
  });
```

and the scroll event is bound to the following code:-

```
 jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function () {

  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 100) {

    jQuery('#headnev').addClass('navbar-fixed-top').removeClass('topnavbar');

    jQuery('body').addClass('bodytopmargin').removeClass('bodynomargin');

  } else {

    jQuery('#headnev').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('topnavbar');

    jQuery('body').removeClass('bodytopmargin').addClass('bodynomargin');

  }
```

});

On a desktop the scroll works as it should for all menu options.

However, on an iPhone (and other small screen smart devices) when the visitor, for example, clicks the "Gallery" menu option, the page scrolls considerably beyond the top of the "Gallery" section such that only the bottom portion of the "Gallery" section is visible on screen. If the visitor next clicks the "Gallery" menu option for a second time, the page scrolls to where it should i.e. to the top of the "Gallery" section. If the visitor next clicks the "Home" menu option the page scrolls as it should to the top of the page but if the visitor then clicks on the "Gallery" menu option the page again scrolls considerably beyond the top of the "Gallery" section. This same behaviour applies to clicks on any of the main menu options.

Furthermore, if the visitor first loads the page and then clicks on the "Gallery" menu option, the page scrolls considerably beyond the top of the "Gallery" section. If the visitor next clicks on any menu option other than the "Home" menu option, then the page correctly scrolls to the top of the selected section. It is only when the visitor clicks on the "Home" menu option and next clicks on any of the other menu options that the page scrolls beyond the top of the selected section.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my post above. After 2 days pulling my hair out I have now discovered that the problem is not caused by any issue with the Bootstrap.

The theme custom css was applying a style to the navbar container which was causing the issue.

Consider this issue resolved.